# Looping function to avoid repeated code in stratified sampling with R

Tags: r, loops, sampling

I am using the code below to perform stratified random sampling of a population, with previously established targets according to gender and region. As can be seen, the same code is repeated three times (every time rbind is used). Is there a way to write a looping function that can repeat this process so that I do not have to write it several times?

```
library(tidyverse)
population<- data.frame(region=rep(c("North", "South", "North", "South"),50000),
                        sex=rep(c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"),50000))

targets<- data.frame(region=c("North", "South", "North", "South"),
                     sex=c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"),
                     total=c(20,25,20,30)) 


n=0
n=n+1
sample<- population %>% filter(region==targets$region[[1]], 
                           sex==targets$sex[[1]]) %>% 
  slice_sample(n=targets$total[[1]])
n=n+1
sample<- sample %>%  rbind(population %>% filter(region==targets$region[[n]], 
                               sex==targets$sex[[n]]) %>% 
  slice_sample(n=targets$total[[n]]))
n=n+1
sample<- sample %>%  rbind(population %>% filter(region==targets$region[[n]], 
                               sex==targets$sex[[n]]) %>% 
  slice_sample(n=targets$total[[n]]))
n=n+1
sample<- sample %>%  rbind(population %>% filter(region==targets$region[[n]], 
                               sex==targets$sex[[n]]) %>% 
  slice_sample(n=targets$total[[n]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. It saves the dfs in a list.

```
n = 4  
sample_list <- list()
for(i in 1:n){
sample<-rbind(population %>% filter(region==targets$region[[i]], 
                                                 sex==targets$sex[[i]]) %>% 
                             slice_sample(n=targets$total[[i]]))
sample_list[[i]] <- sample
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After applying your code followed by  ```bind_rows(sample_list)``` I get a dataframe that is much larger than what it should be. 
The sample dataframe should have 20 males from the north, 25 females from the south and so on (as specified by the "targets" dataset), with a total of 95 observations.

Comment: Just edited the code. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer thanks to the help provided by [Harry Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6684096/harry-smith). It consists of a small tweak of his code:

```
n = 4  
sample_list <- list()
for(i in 1:n){
  sample<- population %>% filter(region==targets$region[[i]], 
                                                   sex==targets$sex[[i]]) %>% 
                               slice_sample(n=targets$total[[i]])
  sample_list[[i]] <- sample
}

a<-bind_rows(sample_list)
```